# IDirectorySearch GetColumn doesn't return actual data ( C++ )

Tags: c++, windows, adsi

I try read some values of attributes from Active Directory by using IDirectorySearch.
When I run my local programm, code works fine. I write IIS7 extention and my code running into w3wp.exe. When code running into w3wp.exe, ExecuteSearch method finds what i need, but GetColumn returns correctly only pszAttrName and dwADsType. In pADsValues i see wrong values ( or uninitialized )

Code:

```
std::string strFromHex(BYTE* data, int length)
{
   std::stringstream ss;

   ss << std::hex;

   for( size_t i=0;i != length; ++i )
      ss << (size_t)data[i];

   return ss.str();
}    

std::string GetGUID()
{    
   std::string guid;
   IDirectorySearch* dSearch;
   hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://DOMEN", L"UserLogin", L"UserPass", ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, IID_IDirectorySearch, (void**)&dSearch);

   if(FAILED(hr))
      return guid;

   LPWSTR searchFilter = L"(&(objectClass=user)(| (userPrincipalName=userLogin*)))";
   LPWSTR att[] = { L"objectGUID" };
   DWORD attCount = 1;
   ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE hSearch;
   ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN col;

   hr = dSearch->ExecuteSearch( searchFilter, att, attCount, &hSearch);

   if(FAILED(hr))
      return guid;

   hr = dSearch->GetFirstRow(hSearch);
   while(S_OK == hr)
   {
      for(DWORD i = 0; i < attCount; i++)
      {
         hr = dSearch->GetColumn(hSearch, att[i], &col);
         if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
         {
            if( col.dwADsType == ADSTYPE_OCTET_STRING )
               guid = strFromHex( col.pADsValues[0].OctetString.lpValue, col.pADsValues[0].OctetString.dwLength );

            dSearch->FreeColumn(&col);
         }
      }
      hr = dSearch->GetNextRow(hSearch);
   }
   hr = dSearch->CloseSearchHandle(hSearch);

   return guid;
}
```

Comment: It's resolved by using OLEBD